# how to make custom range bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to make this custom range bar in android XML.

see below image:

[image]

How do you make this seek range bar in android XML?

If you know any libraries, then comment me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [android-range-seek-bar library](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar)

[image]